# Magento category view drop down pagination?

Tags: magento-1.9, category, pagination

For example, a drop down on the category page which shows a full numeric list of all of the pages within that category. When one of those numbers are selected, it would then go to that page. Not to be confused with, show X per page. This is separate and is not part of the theme I am using?

How can I go about doing this?

Comment: Your Magento version ?

Comment: It is on the latest 1.9 version.